# Yasis alayich, not yasos

Tags: translation, talmud-bavli, isaiah-yeshaya-the-book

The gemara in megillah 10b and Sanhedrin 39b make a diyuk from the word 'yasis', as opposed to 'yasos' in devarim 28,63 that Hashem makes our enemies happy when we sin but he himself is not happy.

In yeshaya 62,5, it says that Hashem will ''yasis'' on yerushalayim when mashiach comes. If we use the diyuk from above, this passuk seems to be saying that Hashem himself will not rejoice with yerushalayim. This seems very odd.

Is there a way to interpret this all such that the gemara's diyuk makes sense yet the passuk is not implying Hashem won't be happy about yerushalayim?

Comment: If yasis means that He will be happy, then what’s the problem?

Comment: @DonielF the gemara says it doesn't

Comment: You said it’s yasos which means He’s not happy, as opposed to yasis used everywhere else.

Comment: @DonielF perhaps I wasn't sufficiently clear, it is yasis which means He is not happy

Comment: I've wondered this.  It's even more glaring since the theme continues the next week in Nitzavim (particularly 29:9), so you're still thinking about it, and then the pasuk in Yeshaya is in the haftara of Nitzavim.

Comment: Probably *Yasus*, no?

Answer (score 1):

In the curses there are 3 parties (our enemies that were already mentioned in passuk 49, Hashem and the Jews) in Devarm 28,63. the word Yasis is referring to our enemies (that were mentioned earlier)  that they will be caused by Hashem to rejoice because of us (destroying us makes them happy we are the punching bag that they rejoice with they are not self content to rejoice on their own ).

With the passuk in Isiah, there are only 2 parties in the Passuk (Hashem and the Jews) so that leaves only one Party to cause us to rejoice with. I.e Hashem causes us to rejoice together with Him. And if Hashem wanted to cause us to rejoice without him it would be written Yasis osoch Elokayich. But it's  written allayich with means on top of you I.e together with you (as proof in the degalim Parshas Bamidbar 2,20 it's written ועליו מטה מנשה which means Menashe encamped together with Ephraim)

And may Hashem cause us to rejoice with Him.

Comment: Where is the third party in the passuk in the curses?

Comment: @MosheSteinberg Devarim 28,49 says ישא ה עליך גוי מרחוק and G-d will mount upon you a nation from afar... they are the same ones whom G-d will cause to rejoice on our downfall in Pasuk 63 look at gittin 56 with titus who is from that nation who rejoiced